# Can't read PR_SECURITY_FLAGS, get random numbers

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I'll try to read the values from PR_SECURITY_FLAGS on Application_ItemSend to see if the mail is "Normal", "Encrypted" or "Signed"

If I send without encryption or signed i get 0 everytime.

But when I change between them I got problem.

For example:

Encrypted checked result 1

Uncheck Encrypted, Signed checked  result 34

Uncheck Signed, Encrypted checked result 33 (Shouldn't this be 1?)

Uncheck Encrypted, Signed unchecked result 32 (Shouldn't this be 0?)

```
string PR_SECURITY_FLAGS = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x6E010003";

             long str = mailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_SECURITY_FLAGS);
            Debug.WriteLine(str);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Dmitry Streblechenko

Since you have to ignore some bits it works with the code:

```
string PR_SECURITY_FLAGS = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x6E010003";

             long str = mailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_SECURITY_FLAGS);

            if (str > 31)
            {
                str = str % 32;
            }
                Debug.WriteLine(str);
```

The flags are:

NONE (=0)

SECFLAG_ENCRYPTED (=1)

SECFLAG_SIGNED (=2)

SECFLAG_ENCRYPTED & SECFLAG_SIGNED (=3)

Answer (score 1):

You only care about two bits `SECFLAG_ENCRYPTED` (=1) and `SECFLAG_SIGNED` (=2)

```
34 = 32 + 2 
33 = 32 + 1
```

There is an undocumented bit flag with the value of 32. You must ignore it and only check the bits you know about.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry Streblechenko.

When I trying around I also get 546, 514 and so on.
So I if I divide it by 32 the rest is 0,1 or 2.

Are there any easy way to do the calculation with C# ?

Comment: Of course - you need to use bitwise operators (& in your case): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/and-operator